# How can I store the value of a user selected option from a drop down select box list into mysql database?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, forms, drop-down-menu

Have a form with a dropdown select box list. How can I store the value of a user selected option from a drop down select box list into mysql database?  Thanks.

**FORM**

```
<form action="xxx.php" class="well" id="xxx" name"xxx" method="post">


<select name="extrafield5">
 <option value="NOW" selected="selected">Submit order now</option>
 <option value="REVIEW">Submit my order for review</option>
<button id="btn1" type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>

</select>


</form>
```

**PHP FILE**

```
<?php

define('DB_NAME', 'xxx');
define('DB_USER', 'xxx');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxx');
define('DB_HOST', 'xxx');

$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if(!$connection){
die('Database connection failed: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($connection, DB_NAME);

if(!$db_selected){
die('Can\'t use ' .DB_NAME . ' : ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

echo 'Connected successfully';


if (isset($_POST['extrafield5'])){
    $extrafield5 = $_POST['extrafield5'];
}

else {$extrafield5 = '';}




$sql = "INSERT INTO seguin_orders (extrafield5) 
        VALUES ('$extrafield5')";

if (!mysqli_query($connection, $sql)){
die('Error: ' . mysqli_connect_error($connection));
}
```

**DATABASE**

http://oi60.tinypic.com/9ppc0i.jpg

Comment: php file returns what?

Comment: Where is your form submit button?

Comment: put print_r($_POST); before database connection to view what you got on that page..

Answer (score 1):

You need to submit the form.

```
<form action="xxx.php" class="well" id="xxx" name"xxx" method="post">
<select name="extrafield5">
 <option value="NOW" selected="selceted">Submit order now</option>
 <option value="REVIEW">Submit my order for review</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

And get it in PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
  if (isset($_POST['extrafield5'])){
    $extrafield5 = $_POST['extrafield5'];
  }
  else {$extrafield5 = '';}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't go to the next page **(xxx.php)** until you submit the form. So please put submit button in the form.

```
<form action="xxx.php" class="well" id="xxx" name"xxx" method="post">
<select name="extrafield5">
 <option value="NOW" selected="selceted">Submit order now</option>
 <option value="REVIEW">Submit my order for review</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

It will resolve the issue.

Comment: im actually using a button which i forgot to include...would that make a difference if im using a button vs a input for a submit button?

Comment: @MarkRodriguez, Inside a `<button>` element you can put content, like text or images. This is the difference between this element and buttons created with the `<input>` element.