# select item value being passed instead of text value into mysql database real time cost calculations

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, select

Have a form that works brilliantly, real time or on the fly cost calculations work, webpage validates etc., and MySQL stores all the info submitted... 
however when the client or me (admin) receive the confirm emails etc., the select options and radio buttons pass the value and not the text which was chosen. The cost calculation total box displays correctly. I'm using Bootstrap HTML 5, PHP and MySQL-(my DB skills are limited though).

Looking at other forums for example this next link is about ASP...
http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/128/get-the-drop-on-asp-net-mvc-dropdownlists

... and what the fella wrote was understandable to my prob.
He quotes  "If you provide a value attribute to an option, that is the value that gets posted back when a form housing the select element is submitted. If you omit the value attribute, the text value of the option gets posted back."

Well i Dont want to omit the value attribute because the cost calculations wont work.

Other Stack questions i looked at are close to answering but dont offer solution.

http://www.bootply.com/128894

```
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22982742/bootstrap-select-option-display-value-instead-of-text

    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27265944/how-can-i-store-the-value-of-a-user-selected-option-from-a-drop-down-select-box
```

I also looked at DBnull.value but havent tried that yet because i need to understand how to do it first.

Anyway if anyone can help here is the script and code i use....

The JS for cost cals. where i placed at the botom of webpage. Works great!!

```
    <script type='text/javascript' >
    function startCalc(){
      interval = setInterval("calc()",1);
    }
    function calc(){
     one = document.autoSumForm.hours.value;
     two = document.autoSumForm.drums.value; 
     three = document.autoSumForm.amp1.value;
     four = document.autoSumForm.amp2.value;
     five = document.autoSumForm.bass.value;
     six = document.autoSumForm.keyboard.value;
     document.autoSumForm.totalBox.value = (one * 1) + (two * 1) + (three * 1) + (four * 1) + (five * 1) + (six * 1);
    }
    function stopCalc(){
    clearInterval(interval);
    }
    </script>
```

Name of form is autoSumForm for the script to reference (id is not needed).
i wont include username email etc.., just the main stuff i'm concerned with.

```
    <form name="autoSumForm" id="autoSumForm">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="hours" class="control-label">For how many Hours</label>
    <div class="input-group">
    <select id="hours" name="hours" class="form-control" onFocus="startCalc();" onBlur="stopCalc();" required>
    <option value="">Choose</option>
    <optgroup label="Minimum 1 Hour">
      <option label="1 hour" value="40.00">1 hour</option>
      <option label="2 hours" value="50.00">2 hours</option>
      <option label="3 hours" value="60.00">3 hours</option>
      <option label="4 hours" value="70.00">4 hours</option>
      <option label="5 hours" value="80.00">5 hours</option>
      <option label="6 hours" value="90.00">6 hours</option>
      <option label="7 hours" value="100.00">7 hours</option>
      <option label="8 hours" value="110.00">8 hours</option>
      <option label="9 hours" value="120.00">9 hours</option>
      <option label="10 hours" value="130.00">10 hours</option>
      <option label="11 hours" value="140.00">11 hours</option>
      <option label="12 hours" value="150.00">12 hours</option>
      </optgroup>
      </select>
       </div>
       </div>

      <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label">Drum Kit Hire</label>
      <div class="radio">
      <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="drums" id="drums_no" value="0.00" onFocus="startCalc();" onBlur="stopCalc();" aria-checked="true" checked="">No</label>
      <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="drums" id="drums" value="10.00" onFocus="startCalc();" onBlur="stopCalc();" aria-checked="false" >Yes</label>
      </div>
       </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">1st Guitar Amp Hire</label>
     <div class="radio"> 
    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="amp1" id="amps1no" value="0.00" onFocus="startCalc();" onBlur="stopCalc();" aria-checked="true" checked="">No</label>
    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="amp1" id="amps1" value="10.00" onFocus="startCalc();" onBlur="stopCalc();" aria-checked="false" >Yes</label>
     </div>
      </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">2nd Guitar Amp Hire</label>
    <div class="radio">
    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="amp2" id="amp2no" value="0.00" onFocus="startCalc();" onBlur="stopCalc();" aria-checked="true" checked="">No</label>
    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="amp2" id="amp2" value="10.00" onFocus="startCalc();" onBlur="stopCalc();" aria-checked="false" >Yes</label>
    </div>
     </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Bass Amp Hire</label>
    <div class="radio">
    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="bass" id="bassno" value="0.00" onFocus="startCalc();" onBlur="stopCalc();" aria-checked="true" checked="">No</label>
   <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="bass" id="bass"  value="10.00" onFocus="startCalc();" onBlur="stopCalc();" aria-checked="false" >Yes</label>
    </div>
    </div>

      <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label">Keyboard Hire</label>
      <div class="radio">
      <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="keyboard" id="keyboardno" value="0.00" onFocus="startCalc();" onBlur="stopCalc();" aria-checked="true" checked="">No</label>
       <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="keyboard" id="keyboard" value="10.00" onFocus="startCalc();" onBlur="stopCalc();" aria-checked="false" >Yes</label>
       </div>
       </div>

        <div class="form-group">
       <label for="totalBox" class="control-label">Projected Costs</label>
      <div class="input-group">
     <input type="text" id="totalBox" name="totalBox" class="form-control" readonly>
      </div>
      </div>

       <div class="form-group">
      <label for="submit" class="control-label">Submit</label>
       <div>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success col-xs-12" name="submit" id="submit" value="Make a Booking">Make a Booking</button>
      </div>
      </div>
     </form>
```

The result i get back in emails:

```
    A new user registered at mywebsite.com
    UserName: batman69
    Email: mymail@mymail.com
    Phone: 0412345678
    Name: robbo
    Bandname: Awesome Stuff
    Date: Thu 30 Apr 2015
    Starting at: 10am
    Hours wanted: 150.00 --  WRONG should be 12 Hours not 150 dollars
    Drum hire: 10.00      --WRONG Should be YES not 10 dollars
    Guitar Amp hire: 0.00    --WRONG Should be NO not zero dollars
    Guitar Amp 2 hire: 10.00   --WRONG Should be YES
    Bass Amp hire: 0.00       --WRONG Should be NO
    Keyboard hire: 10.00      --WRONG Should be YES
    2nd Date: Fri 1 May 2015
    3rd Date: Tue 30 Jun 2015
    4th Date: Wed 30 Sep 2015
    Message enquiry: hey mate the form works but however...
    Projected Costs: 180     --awesome cost calculations work
```

The MySQL script (whick obviously works..but however.. if i were to use DBnull.value how do you do that.. if its needed for hours, drums, amps etc)

```
    function CreateTable()
    {
    $qry = "Create Table $this->tablename (".
            "id_user INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,".
            "username VARCHAR( 17 ) NOT NULL ,".
            "password VARCHAR( 32 ) NOT NULL ,".
            "email VARCHAR( 48 ) NOT NULL ,".
            "phone VARCHAR( 10 ) NOT NULL ,".
            "name VARCHAR( 24 ) NOT NULL ,".
            "bandname VARCHAR( 30 ) NOT NULL ,".
            "datepicker1 VARCHAR( 15 ) NOT NULL ,".
            "hours VARCHAR( 8 ) NOT NULL ,".
            "start VARCHAR( 7 ) NOT NULL ,".
            "drums VARCHAR( 3 ) NOT NULL ,".
            "amp1 VARCHAR( 3 ) NOT NULL ,".
            "amp2 VARCHAR( 3 ) NOT NULL ,".
            "bass VARCHAR( 3 ) NOT NULL ,".
            "keyboard VARCHAR( 3 ) NOT NULL ,".
            "datepicker2 VARCHAR( 15 ) NOT NULL ,".
            "datepicker3 VARCHAR( 15 ) NOT NULL ,".
            "datepicker4 VARCHAR( 15 ) NOT NULL ,".
            "info VARCHAR( 150 ) NOT NULL ,".
            "totalBox VARCHAR( 6 ) NOT NULL ,".
            "confirmcode VARCHAR(32) ,".
            "PRIMARY KEY ( id_user )".
            ")";

          if(!mysql_query($qry,$this->connection))
          {
        $this->HandleDBError("Error creating the table \nquery was\n $qry");
        return false;
       }
       return true;
      }
```

The MySQL insertion into DB works great too..........

```
       function InsertIntoDB(&$formvars)
      {

      $confirmcode = $this->MakeConfirmationMd5($formvars['email']);

       $formvars['confirmcode'] = $confirmcode;

       $insert_query = 'insert into '.$this->tablename.'(
            username,
            password,
            email,
            phone,
            name,
            bandname,
            datepicker1,
            hours,
            start,
            drums,
            amp1,
            amp2,
            bass,
            keyboard,
            datepicker2,
            datepicker3,
            datepicker4,
            info,
            totalBox,
            confirmcode
            )
            values
            (
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['username']) . '",
            "' . md5($formvars['password']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['email']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['phone']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['name']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['bandname']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['datepicker1']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['hours']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['start']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['drums']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['amp1']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['amp2']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['bass']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['keyboard']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['datepicker2']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['datepicker3']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['datepicker4']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['info']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['totalBox']) . '",
            "' . $confirmcode . '"
            )';      
           if(!mysql_query( $insert_query ,$this->connection))
          {
         $this->HandleDBError("Error inserting data to the table\nquery:$insert_query");
        return false;
         }        
         return true;
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed, your scripts are technically valid. 
The form elements are working as specified - they will submit their (checked) value on submit.

Your problem is more a semantical one: the value is meant as the technical representation of the item in the input field. The text representation is just the label to make it human readable (for example, the homepage could be multinational and the label could be in german, english, swedish...depending on the user settings). 
The name attribute and the value attribute together form a sort of key-value store: `drums: yes` (possible values: yes, no).

Of course you can fill in an associated value into the value attribute, but you lose the ability to recognize the selected option once the form is send.

One way to handle your script would be to create a lookup table between the items and their monetary value (in js):

```
var moneys;
moneys['drums']['yes'] = 10.0;
moneys['drums']['no'] = 0.0;
moneys['hours']['h1'] = 40.0;
moneys['hours']['h2'] = 50.0;
//...
// in your calc function:
one = moneys['hours'][document.autoSumForm.hours.value];
two = ['drums'][document.autoSumForm.drums.value]; 
// ....
```